# View fully-resolved value of variable

Tags: ansible

I'm learning Ansible and want to know how to view the fully resolved value of a variable in my playbook. For example:

```yaml
---
- name: A contrived example
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    first_name: Mary
    last_name: Elizabeth
    full_name: "{{first_name}} {{last_name}}"
  tasks:
    - name: Print full name
      debug:
        msg: Hello {{ full_name }}
      debugger: always
```

When stopped in the debugger, I can print the value of `full_name`:

```
(debug)> task_vars["full_name"]
'{{first_name}} {{last_name}}'  # unresolved!
```

How can I resolve it to show `Mary Elizabeth`?

Comment: That's actually the goal of the debugger, to be able to show you an untemplated variable, so you can discover errors more easily. You can do `task_vars["first_name"]` then `task_vars["last_name"]`, and given what `task_vars["full_name"]` gave you you can deduct what it will be, when templated.

Comment: The Ansible playbook that I inherit from the previous developer was significantly more complicated. `var1: root`, `var2: {{var1}}/something`, `var3: {{var2}}/anotherThing`... So I just want to see the final, templated value to help me understand it